# What is the name of the triangle formed by the external angle bisectors of a triangle?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, terminology, triangles

The purple triangle below is the original triangle ABC and the red triangle is constructed from the purple one by taking the external angle bisectors of ABC.

I am wondering if the red triangle has a particular name, since there is an important duality between the orthic triangle (purple) and the unknown name red triangle.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the lettering and other ornamentation in the diagram suggest, the angle bisectors meet at the incentre and the red triangle is the [anticevian](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/AnticevianTriangle.html) with respect to that point, which is therefore the [excentral triangle](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ExcentralTriangle.html).